# How to generate object from xml steam using xsd?

Tags: c#, xsd

I get some a xml file and a xsd. 
I generated the xsd to classes ( c# file ).

How do i generate a class from the this xml **in run time** according to my xsd class that i hold ?

Comment: yes - but all the exmples does not contain any reference to the xsd and this is not in run time as i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're mixing up the jargon. You use the XSD to generate a class. Then you deserialize the XML into an instance of that class, i.e. an object.

You don't need to generate a class at runtime, and frankly - you don't want to.

So just deserialize your XML to an object as explained on MSDN and various other Q&As.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourXsdClass));
using (someReader = YourXmlReader)
{
    StepList result = (YourXsdClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```